# How can a negative strangelet convert matter in strange matter?

Tags: standard-model, matter

How can a [strangelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet) convert matter into strange matter?
Because strange quarks are heavier than up and down quarks wouldn't you loose energy by converting regular matter into strange matter?
And are there any other non-theoretical particles that can actually convert matter in something else?

Comment: The WP article you quote expressly reminds you that since strange quarks do not Pauli-exclude *u* or *d* quarks, the Fermi energy of a large body of quarks may be lowered by weak processes effectively converting *d* to *s* quarks, overcoming the mass difference by a lot. This is analogous to neutrons in nuclei being stable.

Answer (score -1):

One possible answer is that when quark matter is generated the energy of the gluons drops compared to the their energy in nuclear matter.